# Is it possible Logstash push same content from log file to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-file

The `logstash` config sets log files as input source and then sends the content to `ElasticSearch`.

The `input` part is like below

```
input{
    file{
        path => "/data/logs/backend.log*"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
```

Then the log file will be rolling by size, which means at first the log file name is `backend.log`, when the file reaches size 10M, then it is renamed to `backend.log.1`, and a new empty backend.log is created to log content.

So the question is whether `logstash` will send the content from `backend.log.1` to es server? Or is `ElasticSearch` able to distinguish that the content from `backend.log.1` already received, although this seems to be not efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file` input documentation contains a whole paragraph about how well it handles [rotation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#_file_rotation_in_tail_mode)

> File rotation is detected and handled by this input, regardless of whether the file is rotated via a rename or a copy operation. To support programs that write to the rotated file for some time after the rotation has taken place, include both the original filename and the rotated filename (e.g. /var/log/syslog and /var/log/syslog.1) in the filename patterns to watch (the path option).

Since the `tail` mode is the default, your `path` parameter should make sure to use a glob pattern to catch all files, exactly as you did. So you're all set. Happy tailing!